# Can I pass arrays as a "ParamArray"?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

What I'm trying to do is to pass an undefined number of multidimensional arrays (to create a matrix multiplication function).

Something like this:

```
Sub main()

Dim A_out2 as Double(,)
Dim A_out3 as Double(,)
Dim A1 as Double(,) = {{1,2}, {3,4}}

A_out2 = matXmat(A1, A1)

A_out3 = matXmat(A1, A1, A1)

end sub


'I know this is wrong, but you get what I'm trying to do:

function matXmat(ByVal ParramArray args(,) as Double()) as Double(,)

'Number of matrices

dim numMat as double = args.length

'Matrix multiplication loop

end function
```

Comment: you could just put the arrays in an ArrayList or List(of T):  `Function matXmat(args As ArrayList) As Double(,)` args.COunt would tell you how may arrays there are.

Comment: `ParamArray args() As Double` maybe - ParamArray has to be a 1-D array (inside can be 2-Ds)

Comment: I Add more alternatives: **Public Function matXmat(ByVal args As Collection) As Double(,)** Or else **Public Function matXmat(ByVal A1 As Double(,), ByVal A2 As Double(,)) As Double(,)** the latter alternative can be called repeatedly with an accumulator variable to obtain the final result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter can be a jagged array, such as the following:

```
ParamArray args As Double()(,)
```

Using this, my test based on your example compiles.

You can retrieve the first 2 dimensional array from the parameter as follows:

```
Dim test(,) As Double = args(0) 'etc.
```

You were on the right track, but you can't have your array specifiers both after the type and after the parameter name - they need to be in just one spot (e.g., ParamArray args As Double()(,) or ParamArray args()(,) As Double).

Answer (score 1):

Here I'll explain a bit more about the last alternative I gave you in the comments:

```
'For example:
Dim A1 As Double(,) = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
Dim A2 As Double(,) = {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}
Dim A3 As Double(,) = {{9, 0}, {1, 2}}

Dim result As Double(,) = matXmat(A1, A2)   ' result = A1 x A2

result = matXmat(result, A3)   ' result = A1 x A2 x A3

' If exists one more matrix then
'result = matXmat(result, A4)   ' result = A1 x A2 x A3 x A4
```

Comment: Thanks! So I actually ended up combining both so that I just have a single function.